# send to repository class variable laravel from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i´m traying to do query into my repository to get galleries that to have a restaurant and i need seach for id. One restaurant´s gallery only can to have 10 images, but we can to have more than one restaurant. I need that when one restaurant will have a 10 images, it can´t upload any more and disable this restaurant.

sorry for my english, i hope that i can explain me correctly.

**my controller:**

```
if (auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')){
            $restaurant = $this->restaurantRepository->pluck('name', 'id');
        }else{
            $restaurant = $this->restaurantRepository->galleries()->myActiveRestaurants()->pluck('name', 'id');
        }
        // get all media gallery of restaurant
        //$media = $this->galleryRepository->getCountMedia();
        foreach($restaurant as $res){
            $res->cg = (count($res->galleries()->get()) == 10);
        }

        $hasCustomField = in_array($this->galleryRepository->model(), setting('custom_field_models', []));
        if ($hasCustomField) {
            $customFields = $this->customFieldRepository->findByField('custom_field_model', $this->galleryRepository->model());
            $html = generateCustomField($customFields);
        }
        return view('galleries.create')->with("customFields", isset($html) ? $html : false)->with("restaurant", $restaurant)/*->with('imagesRestaurant', $media)*/;
```

here i´m calling to model function galleries() where i have a function to get, `restaurant_id`

but in my web, result is:

```
Call to a member function galleries() on string
```

i need to get `restaurant_id` for call here `my repository`:

```
public function getCountMedia(){
        return Gallery::join("user_restaurants", "user_restaurants.restaurant_id", "=", "galleries.restaurant_id")
                        ->where('user_restaurants.user_id', auth()->id())->count();
    }
```

i don´t want `auth()->id()` i need `restaurant_id` for in my controller extract that restaurant to have 10 image

i hope that any can help me, please

**updated**

i´m instaciate class in construct:

```
public function __construct(GalleryRepository $galleryRepo, CustomFieldRepository $customFieldRepo, UploadRepository $uploadRepo
        , RestaurantRepository $restaurantRepo)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->galleryRepository = $galleryRepo;
        $this->customFieldRepository = $customFieldRepo;
        $this->uploadRepository = $uploadRepo;
        $this->restaurantRepository = $restaurantRepo;
    }
```

i can show now, that `restaurant_id` it´s in galleries table, but i don´t know how to access to this property

**updated2**

i change my controller and repository:

**controller**

```
// get all media gallery of restaurant
foreach($restaurant as $res => $id){
   $media[] = $this->galleryRepository->getCountMedia($res);
}
return view('galleries.create')->with("customFields", isset($html) ? $html : false)->with("restaurant", $restaurant)->with('imagesRestaurant', $media);
```

**repository**

```
public function getCountMedia($restaurantId){
        return Gallery::join("user_restaurants", "user_restaurants.restaurant_id", "=", "galleries.restaurant_id")
                        ->where('galleries.restaurant_id', $restaurantId)->count();
    }
```

with this i get id for restaurant, and in blade i need disable option that value greater than 10 but, only get duplicate select...

**blade:**

```
@foreach($imagesRestaurant as $images)
      {{$images}}
    
      @if($images >= 10)
        {!! Form::select('restaurant_id', $restaurant, null, ['class' => 'select2 form-control']) !!}
      @else
        {!! Form::select('restaurant_id', $restaurant, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'disabled' => true]) !!}
      @endif
    @endforeach
```

Comment: where your calling repository ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul thanks for your response, in this line $media = $this->galleryRepository->getCountMedia(); but this line it´s commentd because i need to do this for restaurant. For this i have a for-each but i don´t know very well this

Comment: `Call to a member function galleries() on string` for this `$this->restaurantRepository->galleries()` here `restaurantRepository` where your creating instance ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul i updated my question. i have to say that "restaurant_id" it´s in galleries table, but i don´t know how to pass this property to repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something link this

```php
public function __construct($restaurant_id)
{
    parent::__construct();
    dd($restaurant_id);
    $this->galleryRepository = new GalleryRepository(); // if you need you can pass here 
    $this->customFieldRepository = new CustomFieldRepository();
    $this->uploadRepository = new UploadRepository();
    $this->restaurantRepository = new RestaurantRepository();
}
```

here whenever your calling this class you need to pass `restaurant_id` like new `ClassName($restaurant_id)`

---

### Update

you can create instance of repo and pass value like this

```php
// get all media gallery of restaurant
foreach ($restaurant as $res => $id) {
    $media[] = (new GalleryRepository($id))->getCountMedia($res);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. i change all my code, i update my question, if you can help me with this, I would be very grateful with you

Comment: thanks for your response, but GalleryRepository haven´t got construct, have a method getCountMedia only, in my update2 i´m getting that i´m need, but in blade i´m duplicating select, but i need disable option that it have 10 or more images

Comment: @daviserraalonso what is inside `$imagesRestaurant` ?

Comment: it´s my variable that i´m passing from controller to view, that contain numer of images from gallerie from restaurant. i updated my question, in controller section inside update2

Comment: so you means `disabled` attribute is not working ?

Comment: disabled all select

Comment: it's means all count is greater then 10

Comment: finally I have opted for to do this question otherwise, in my method store, if images > 10 return exit with message